# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "print" y "return" al final de una función en Python? ? ¿"?

Tags: python-3.x

```python
def suma(x, y):
    z = x + y
    print(z)


def suma(x, y):
    return a + b
```

Cuando se ejecutan ambas funciones,  la función que termina con "print" muestra resultado, sin embargo la función que termina con "return", no muestra resultado.

Comment: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-funciones-2.html

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y leiste la documentacion de lo que haca cada una? porque no tienen nada que ver una con otra...

Comment: Tú mismo te has respondido! :-) `print()` muestra lo que le pidas mostrar (`z` en el caso de la primera función). La segunda función no tiene `print()` por tanto no muestra nada. Pero tiene un `return` que devuelve el resultado a la función que la llamó, por lo que esa otra función puede tener el `print()` necesario. Puede hacer por ejemplo `print(suma(3,2))`. Este segundo enfoque es más genérico pues la función que llamó puede elegir si quiere mostrar el resultado, o guardarlo para otra cosa como con `s = suma(3,2)`, cosa que la primera función no permite porque no retorna nada.

Comment: +1. MIrandolo por el lado positivo, ha sido capaz de presentar su caso impecablemente.

Comment: No es un problema, si no parte del aprendizaje básico de cualquier lenguaje de programación. Debes estudiar y practicar un poco más y lo vas a tener claro ;) . [Referencia de Funciones](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 2):

cuando ejecutas una funcion puedes hacer varias cosas dentro de ella:

**1. print:** imprime lo que tenga dentro de los paréntesis () puede ser una variable o un valor.
nota: esto se puede hacer en cualquier parte de la funcion.

**2. return:** esto finaliza la funcion y retorna lo que tengas a la derecha; puede ser una variable, objeto o un valor.

En este ejemplo:

```
return a + b
```

lo que se esta haciendo es que en la misma linea de la finalización de la funcion se ejecuta la suma de **a+b** y como return tambien retorna lo que eta a su derecha entonces retornará el resultado de dicha suma.

*Te recomendaría que busques un tutorial de programación con python desde 0 ya que esto es muy básico y es algo minimo que debes saber antes de iniciar a programar.*

Answer (score 0):

El return te devuelve un valor de resultado en caso de ejecutarse una operacion, el print escribe en la consola.
print() sirve para mostrar un mensaje en la pantalla de una aplicación de consola, mientras que return se utiliza para establecer el resultado (o valor de retorno) de una función. Así, return es una operación mucho más genérica que print(), aunque solo puede usarse dentro de las funciones: no puede haber un return en cualquier otro lugar del código que no sea el interior de una función.
print() solo puede usarse, naturalmente, en aplicaciones de consola, pues sirve únicamente para mostrar un mensaje en la consola (o terminal, línea de comandos, símbolo del sistema, etc.)